# How can I judge the javascript object whether have a child object

Tags: javascript, object

suppose I have a object:

```
obj:{
   child:{
      x:12,
      y:50
   },
   key1:"value1",
   key2:"value2"
}
```

if I want to traverse the object,like:

```
for (var i in obj) {

}
```

How can I judge whether the object have child object,so I could traverse it.I know I could use `hasOwnProperty` method, but in this situation, I have no idea about what the child object name is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check if a property contains an Object:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && obj[i] instanceof Object) {
        // obj[i] is a child object
    }
}
```

A note of precaution: remember that Functions and Arrays are both Objects in Javascript. You can test individually for those using `instanceof Function` and `instance of Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this snippet will help you:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log(typeof obj[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Function:

```
var obj = { a : { aa : 'aa'
                , ab : 'ab' }
          , b : 'b'
          , c : 'c'
          };


function listKeyValue (o){
   for (var prop in o){
      if(typeof o[prop] === 'object') 
         listKeyValue(o[prop]);
      else 
         console.log(prop,o[prop]);
   }
}

listKeyValue(obj);
```